# How do I move a position of an object in Swift?

Tags: ios, swift, uiview

I have an object I'm trying to animate to roll across the screen. I don't know how to change the position of the object and make it spin more than it is already. This is what I have so far:

```
@IBOutlet weak var quarterImage: UIImageView!

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
    UIView.animateWithDuration(8.0, animations: {
        let angle = CGFloat(-4000)
        let rotate = CGAffineTransformMakeRotation(angle)
        self.quarterImage.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeRotation(angle)
    })

}
```

Any help would be great. Thanks!

Comment: Look into changing the frame property of the object from within the animations block. Also note that the version of animateWithDuration  that takes an options bitmask allows for indefinitely recurring and autoreversing animations, as well as specified animation curves.

Answer (score 1):

I am using some bouncing animation of a smiley face image which jumps repeatedly.
Here is the code so that you can have idea about changing position.
For rotation I guess you need to play around with different PI values of angle to get smooth rotation.

**Swift 2**

```
UIView.animateWithDuration(0.6, delay: 0.3, options: [UIViewAnimationOptions.Autoreverse, UIViewAnimationOptions.Repeat, UIViewAnimationOptions.CurveEaseOut], animations:
    {
        self.m_smileyImgView?.transform.ty -= 30;

    },completion: nil);
```

**Swift 3,4,5**

```
UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.6, delay: 0.3, options: [UIView.AnimationOptions.autoreverse, UIView.AnimationOptions.repeat, UIView.AnimationOptions.curveEaseOut], animations:
    {
        self.m_smileyImgView?.transform.ty -= 30;

},completion: nil);
```

Answer (score 0):

`CGAffineTransformMakeRotation` can be a little tricky

First of all, it expects degrees in radians

Second of all, values over 2PI doesn't matter (0 = 2PI = 6PI = 10000PI)

**Here is an example function for rotating an image 360 degrees**

```
func rotateImage(times times:Int) {
    if times == 0 { return }
    UIView.setAnimationCurve(.Linear)
    UIView.animateKeyframesWithDuration(1, delay: 0, options: .CalculationModeLinear, animations: {
        UIView.addKeyframeWithRelativeStartTime(0, relativeDuration: 1/3, animations: {
            self.imageView.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeRotation(CGFloat(M_PI * 2/3))
        })
        UIView.addKeyframeWithRelativeStartTime(1/3, relativeDuration: 1/3, animations: {
            self.imageView.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeRotation(CGFloat(M_PI * 4/3))
        })
        UIView.addKeyframeWithRelativeStartTime(2/3, relativeDuration: 1/3, animations: {
            self.imageView.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeRotation(CGFloat(M_PI * 2))
        })
    }) { (_) in
        self.rotateImage(times: times - 1)
    }
}
```

If you want to move the object while you rotate, you can change its position by adding this keyframe

```
UIView.addKeyframeWithRelativeStartTime(0, relativeDuration: 1.0, animations: { 
                self.imageView.center.x += 50
            })
```